# Why CSS is not working on my github pages?

Tags: css, reactjs, github, deployment, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my react app on github as pages but the css isn't working. Im attaching my github repository if anyone can help.[text](https://github.com/um3ranwar/IStore).

As right now the page is looking totally messed cause not css is applied.

Answer (score 1):

cLooking at generated `index.html` file in the `gh-pages` branch, I can see that the file is malformed; you have missing closing tags in your HTML.

```
// index.html (I added newlines for readability)
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link>font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif; href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren|Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"
      <link>rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"
    ...
```

Notice the `link` tags aren't closed. Because of this, the CSS file will not be loaded by the browser.

Comment: I added the closing tags but still there is no CSS implemented.